# How to handle the assignment operation for structures with pointers?

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure definition which I need to control the assignment operator for. Here is some example code that doesn't work how I want yet.

```
struct jsonobject {
    struct jsonobject* children[100];
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct jsonobject obj;
    struct jsonobject obj2;
    
    obj2 = obj; // Problem is here.
    
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that the line `obj2 = obj` performs a shallow copy of the `obj` when I need it to perform a deep copy. How am I supposed to handle cases like this?

Comment: you need to write a function that takes care of this.

Comment: You need to handle this yourself. Like e.g. `obj2 = DeepCopyObj(&obj);`.

Comment: Note that you also have to write functions to initialize, allocate and free that *big* tree object.

Comment: Using a language that is not C is another possibility worth considering.

Comment: Unless your purpose is to build a JSON library, just use one that already exists.

Comment: @n.m. Another language such as C++ would give exactly the same problem. In C++ you would have to add an overloaded assignment operator in order to make this code work. Similarly in C, you will have to add a helper function of some kind. It's not related to the language. The main problem here is that the internals of a struct is exposed to the user, which shouldn't be messing around with them in the first place. In C++ the solution would be a class. In C the solution would be an opaque type. There only major difference is that C++ has RAII so you don't need to call constructors explicitly.

Comment: @Lundin The difference is that in C++ `a = b` does the right thing, and in C it does not. I quote the OP, "I need it to perform a deep copy", end of quote. That's after you write the needed helper functions in both languages. And of course there are more languages out there than just C and C++.

Comment: @n.m. Rather, in case you have implemented these as C++ classes but didn't overload assignment operator, then C++ does the wrong thing. As opposed to the equivalent C code with opaque types where you wouldn't be able to allocate instances of the variables to begin with, so it wouldn't compile. Or in case of struct pointers, it does a shallow copy too in either language.

Comment: @Lundin Nice strawman, but I don't have time to watch it burn.

Comment: @n.m. The main point here is that switching to C++ will not mean that the necessary code is written for you by magic, or that the program design magically turns sound and proper.

Comment: @Lundin Nobody implied that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function which performs the deep copy recursively. Here is a demonstration which allocates memory for the copy using `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CHILDREN 5

struct jsonobject {
    struct jsonobject* children[MAX_CHILDREN];
};

void deep_print( const struct jsonobject *obj );
struct jsonobject *deep_copy( const struct jsonobject *src );
void deep_free( struct jsonobject *obj );

int main( void )
{
    //construct jsonobject with two layers of children
    struct jsonobject child3child1 =
    {
        {
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL
        }
    };
    struct jsonobject child1 =
    {
        {
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL
        }
    };
    struct jsonobject child3 =
    {
        {
            NULL,
            &child3child1,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL
        }
    };
    struct jsonobject root =
    {
        {
            NULL,
            &child1,
            NULL,
            &child3,
            NULL
        }
    };

    //deep print the source data
    printf( "Deep print of source data: \n\n" );
    deep_print( &root );

    //perform the deep copy
    struct jsonobject *copy = deep_copy( &root );

    //deep print the copied data
    printf( "\n\nDeep print of copied data: \n\n" );
    deep_print( copy );

    //cleanup
    deep_free( copy );
}

void deep_print( const struct jsonobject *obj )
{
    // NOTE: This function is not thread-safe, because of the use
    //       of this static variable.
    static int depth = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; i++ )
    {
        //add indentation according to depth
        for ( int j = 0; j < depth; j++ )
            printf( "----" );

        if ( obj->children[i] == NULL )
        {
            printf( "children[%d] is NULL\n", i );
        }
        else
        {
            printf(
                "children[%d] points to %p which contains the following:\n",
                i, (void*)obj->children[i]
            );
            depth++;
            deep_print( obj->children[i] );
            depth--;
        }
    }
}

struct jsonobject *deep_copy( const struct jsonobject *src )
{
    //allocate memory for new struct
    struct jsonobject *new_struct = malloc( sizeof *new_struct );
    if ( new_struct == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //recursively copy all children
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; i++ )
    {
        if ( src->children[i] == NULL )
        {
            new_struct->children[i] = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            //perform a recursive deep copy
            new_struct->children[i] = deep_copy( src->children[i] );
        }
    }

    return new_struct;
}

void deep_free( struct jsonobject *obj )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; i++ )
    {
        if ( obj->children[i] != NULL )
        {
            deep_free( obj->children[i] );
        }
    }

    free( obj );
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I reduced `MAX_CHILDREN` from `100` to `5`. For the code in your question, you want `MAX_CHILDREN` to have the value `100`.

This demonstration program has the following output:

```
Deep print of source data: 

children[0] is NULL
children[1] points to 0x7ffc58161500 which contains the following:
----children[0] is NULL
----children[1] is NULL
----children[2] is NULL
----children[3] is NULL
----children[4] is NULL
children[2] is NULL
children[3] points to 0x7ffc58161550 which contains the following:
----children[0] is NULL
----children[1] points to 0x7ffc581614b0 which contains the following:
--------children[0] is NULL
--------children[1] is NULL
--------children[2] is NULL
--------children[3] is NULL
--------children[4] is NULL
----children[2] is NULL
----children[3] is NULL
----children[4] is NULL
children[4] is NULL


Deep print of copied data: 

children[0] is NULL
children[1] points to 0x604000000050 which contains the following:
----children[0] is NULL
----children[1] is NULL
----children[2] is NULL
----children[3] is NULL
----children[4] is NULL
children[2] is NULL
children[3] points to 0x604000000090 which contains the following:
----children[0] is NULL
----children[1] points to 0x6040000000d0 which contains the following:
--------children[0] is NULL
--------children[1] is NULL
--------children[2] is NULL
--------children[3] is NULL
--------children[4] is NULL
----children[2] is NULL
----children[3] is NULL
----children[4] is NULL
children[4] is NULL
```

As you can see, the structure of the source data was successfully copied. Also, the addresses of the children of the copied data are different to those of the source data. This proves that a deep copy, not a shallow copy, was performed.

Comment: Of course, the next step is to make this multithread-safe...  :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I can think of two ways to do that: 1. Make the `static` variable `depth` `_Thread_local`. 2. Make the variable a function parameter instead of a local `static` variable. However, I won't do #2 in my program, because I want to keep the function `main` as simple as possible, so I don't want to add an additional parameter to the function `deep_print`, because the depth is supposed to be only an implementation detail of the function. I guess I could do #1, but I'm not sure if using thread-local storage (TLS) would cause a negative performance impact.

Answer (score 4):

- `memcpy(&obj2, &obj, sizeof obj)` like `obj2 = obj` in this example creates a shallow copy (if your object contains pointers those are copied not whatever they pointer to).
- You will need a (custom) function to create a deep copy.  You will probably want to store number of children in your struct unless you use a sentinel (NULL).

JSON libraries ship with suitable functions, and usually, a mechanism to share data via reference counts.